# What does "to go to school on someone" mean?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms

This phrase was used when a person addressing other people said:

> You went to school on us

Comment: If it's from [here](http://www.newsmax.com/Newsfront/gen-mark-milley-enemies-test-us-military/2016/10/04/id/751701/), then it means *learned at our expense*. If not, give us the context.

Comment: You are right, this is exactly where I heard this phrase. Could you please clarify for me what exactly this means: _learned at our expense_. In that context does it mean that they copied _us_?

Comment: The answer to your question is in the following paragraph, if you read it.

Comment: I've read the article. I'm unclear what the phrase means. I understand the words, but not he exact meaning. I came here to clarify. So I'd very appreciate a detailed answed that would clarify this for me.

Comment: it's a **bad and messy** variation of "he schooled us".  (which is simply the same as the older phrase "he taught us a lesson")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide the sentence into two parts:

> Our enemies **went to school** ...

means *our enemies **learned***.

> ... on us.

means ***at our expense***, i.e. we provided the means for them to learn.

> "They studied our doctrine, our tactics, our equipment, our
>   organization, our training, our leadership," he said. "And, in turn,
>   they revised their own doctrines, and they are rapidly modernizing
>   their military today to avoid our strengths in hopes of defeating us
>   at some point in the future."

He's saying they were able to learn by studying the example we have provided.

---

> In that context does it mean that they copied us?

No, it means they have learned how to operate against us, using their own methods.

Comment: qwaz, it's very much worth realising ***it is NOT a 'standard phrase'***, the General in question was deliberately using language in an odd way: he was making a new construction by changing-around other constructions. You see?  Note that to my ear, for example, it just sounds: totally stupid. It sounds like the General is confused, **was talking in a hurry**, and can't express himself clearly. It sounds like he was "trying to say something clever", but since stupid, it just came out confused: indeed I'm still **totally unclear what exactly he meant**, having read the whole thing.

Comment: I appreciate you pointing this out to me, this is good to know. Thanks.